# Bootstrap Input-Group Multiple Textbox Widths

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 textboxes in an input-group, seperated by an input-group-addon span. My problem is, I want textbox 1 to be wider than textbox 2. Textbox 1 is supposed to be the phone number (larger) and textbox 2 is an extension number (slimmer). I have a fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhhj7f5d/

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">Ext.</span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Extension"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width to your form

```html
<div class="col-xs-6">
 <div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">Ext.</span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Extension" style="width : 20px;"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

or use css

Comment: If I manually shrink the second textbox, the entire input group becomes smaller. If I then compensate by increasing the size of the first textbox, the span in the middle gets covered up. I think it's something to do with the table cell display?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your input tag inside a div with col-xs-*.

```css
#phoneField .col-xs-3{
  padding:0;
}
#phoneField .col-xs-3::after{
  content: "-";
  position:absolute;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div id="phoneField" class="input-group">
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ext" maxlength="3"/>
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="10"/>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```